# How to use getContentResolver() inside non activity class?

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am trying to create a method which retrieves contact name for the given input string. For that I have to use `getContentResolver` method. To use the context I am passing the context as the parameter. But still the following error is populating.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.ContentResolver
>   android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object
>   reference

```
public class GetContactName {

    public static String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

        String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME};

        String contactName = "";
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                contactName = cursor.getString(0);
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

        return contactName;
    }

}
```

Please help me to solve this

Comment: You are passing `null` as context in `getContactName`.

Comment: From where @ADM

Comment: From where are you calling this method ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While calling getContactName(), call that with non null attribute

```
getContactName(getActivity(), phoneNumber);
```

where `getActivity()` represents the context of the class from where you are calling this method. 
You may be passing a null reference instead of passing the proper context.

Comment: If I use `this` it says `Change 1st parameter of method from Context to MyFragment` So I created a global context variable and used here

Comment: So you are calling this function from a fragment. Then instead of passing 'this' pass the context of the class from where you are calling the fragment.

Comment: @deluxan use `getActivity()` in `fragment` instead of this i.e `getContactName(getActivity(), phoneNumber);`

Comment: I have edited the answer. please check.

Answer (score 0):

you can create one singleton class for the app form it's instance you can access contentResolver()